# Looking for a more robust way to automatically resize contents to viewport

Tags: css

I'm trying to keep an `svg:rect` sized to fit exactly in the visible viewport (with a 20px margin), irrespective of resizing of said viewport.  I'm doing this with JS (and friends)<sup>1</sup>, but I find that this approach is not very robust (nor particularly responsive, for that matter).  (E.g. there are hard-to-reproduce situations in which the size of one of the margins is twice as big as it should be, or when a vertical scrollbar pops up for no obvious reason.)

***BUT*** the purpose of this post is *not* to find better JS for solving this problem, since I am convinced that this problem is really not a job for JS; it should be dealt with via a suitable CSS spec.  (The only reason I resorted to JS for it is that all my efforts at doing it with CSS failed, but then again, I know that I am *severely* CSS-challenged.)

So my question is: What's the proper CSS for this?

---

<sup>1</sup> For completeness, this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXZW7/)** shows (though not very accurately, unfortunately) what I'm doing now, but the essence of it is in this JS snippet:

```
(function ($) {
  var margin = 20,
      viewport = document.documentElement,
      canvas = d3.select('#canvas'),
      voodoo = 5,   // wards off evil v-scrollbar spirits
      hmargin = 2 * margin,
      vmargin = 2 * margin + voodoo;

  $('body').css('margin', margin);
  resize_canvas();
  $(window).on('resize orientationChanged', resize_canvas);

  function resize_canvas () {
    canvas.attr({width: viewport.clientWidth - hmargin,
                 height: viewport.clientHeight - vmargin});
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want through pure css

If you add a container around your `svg` and add the following attributes to your `rect`:

```
<div id="margin-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <rect id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(255,255,255);"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
```

You can use the following css:

```
html {height:100%;}
body,
html {padding:0; margin:0; background:black; position:relative; width:100%; min-height:100%;}
#margin-container {position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px; left:20px; bottom:20px;}
svg {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/nXZW7/8/)